# Azure Pipeline for .NET Core 3.0 P9 does not work

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, devops

I have a simple Blazor project using 3.0 P9 which builds fine on my local machine, checked it into azure devops, created a pipe getting

> C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\dotnet\sdk\3.0.100-preview9-014004\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(234,5):
>   Error NETSDK1004: Assets file
>   'd:\a\1\s\projectname\obj\project.assets.json' not found. Run a
>   NuGet package restore to generate this file.  Process 'msbuild.exe'
>   exited with code '1'.

when running the pipeline with following yaml (task UseDotNet@2 and DotNetCoreInstaller@0 were added to the default generated pipeline code)

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest' 

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
- task: DotNetCoreInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Install .net core 3.0 (preview)'
  inputs:
    version: '3.0.100-preview9-014004'

- task: UseDotNet@2
  inputs:
    version: 3.x
    includePreviewVersions: true
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet restore'
  inputs:
    command: restore
    projects: '**/projectname.csproj'
- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'

- task: VSTest@2
  inputs:
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this fixed it for me

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Install .net core 3.0 (preview)'
  inputs:
    version: '3.0.100-preview9-014004'

- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
```

Answer (score 1):

> Azure Pipeline for .NET Core 3.0 P9 does not work

To resolve this issue, please add a `dotnet restore` task before the task `Visual Studio build`:

```
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2

  displayName: 'dotnet restore'

  inputs:

    command: restore

    projects: '**/YourProjectName.csproj'

    vstsFeed: 'XXXX'
```

The error occurs because the dotnet cli does not create the all of the required files initially. Doing dotnet restore adds the required files.

Hope this helps.

Comment: now i am getting this error.. i updated the yaml based on your comments to show latest yaml in the OP
 Error CS8652: The feature 'nullable reference types' is currently in Preview and *unsupported*. To use Preview features, use the 'preview' language version."

Comment: After further research I found that the .NET Core 3.0 SDK is in a prerelease state, it's not officialy supported by release Visual Studio, and the SDK team recommends using preview Visual Studios for projects that use preview SDKs. So, we may need to build this project with private agent and preview Visual Studio. Since you are using the `windows-latest`, this may be the reason you got this error, check this ticket: https://github.com/dotnet/arcade/issues/3035#issuecomment-502720454

Comment: I dont have that option in my vs as i am already using vs2019 preview 3, my problem is nothing to do with building locally, which works both in debug and release without any problems.  i tried  `windows-latest` which vs2019 and win2016 and none of the agents https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops offer one for vs2019 preview.